# Terraform lambda invocation probable timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

After having spent 7 hours on this, I decided to reach out to you.
I need to update credentials within in a terraform flow. Since the secrets shall not be in the state-file, I use an AWS lambda function to update the secret of the RDS instance. The password is passed via CLI.

```
   locals {
  db_password = tostring(var.db_user_password)
}

data "aws_lambda_invocation" "credentials_manager" {
  function_name = "credentials-manager"
  input = <<JSON
{
  "secretString": "{\"username\":\"${module.db_instance.db_user}\",\"password\":\"${local.db_password}\",\"dbInstanceIdentifier\":\"${module.db_instance.db_identifier}\"}",
  "secretId": "${module.db_instance.db_secret_id}",
   "storageId": "${module.db_instance.db_identifier}",
   "forcedMod": "${var.forced_mod}"
}
JSON

    depends_on = [
    module.db_instance.db_secret_id,
  ]
}


output "result" {
  description = "String result of Lambda execution"
  value       = jsondecode(data.aws_lambda_invocation.credentials_manager.result)
}
```

In order to make sure that the RDS instance status is 'available' the lambda function also contains a waiter.
When I manually execute the function everything works like a charm.
But within in terraform it does not proceed from here:

```
data.aws_lambda_invocation.credentials_manager: Refreshing state...
```

However, when I look into AWS Cloud Watch I can see that the lambda function is being invoked by Terraform over and over again.

This is the lambda policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1589715377799",
      "Action": [
        "rds:ModifyDBInstance",
        "rds:DescribeDBInstances"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The lambda function looks like this:

```js
const secretsManager = require('aws-sdk/clients/secretsmanager')
const rds = require('aws-sdk/clients/rds')
const elastiCache = require('aws-sdk/clients/elasticache')
const log = require('loglevel')


/////////////////////////////////////////
// ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
/////////////////////////////////////////
const logLevel = process.env["LOG_LEVEL"];
const region = process.env["REGION"]


/////////////////////////////////////////
// CONFIGURE LOGGER
log.setLevel(logLevel);
let protocol = []

/////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////
// DEFINE THE CLIENTS
const SM = new secretsManager({ region })
const RDS = new rds({ region })
const ELC = new elastiCache({region})
/////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////
// FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
/////////////////////////////////////////


// HELPERS

/**
 * @function waitForSeconds
 * Set a custom waiter.
 * 
 * @param {int} milseconds      - the milliseconds to set as timeout.
 * 
 */

const waitForSeconds = (ms) => {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}




// AWS SECRETS MANAGER FUNCTIONS

/**
 * @function UpdateSecretInSM
 * The function updates the secrect value in the corresponding secret.
 * 
 * @param {string} secretId      - The id of the secret located in AWS SecretsManager 
 * @param {string} secretString  - The value of the new secret
 * 
 */
const UpdateSecretInSM = async (secretId,secretString) => {

    const params = {SecretId: secretId, SecretString: secretString}



    try {
        const data = await SM.updateSecret(params).promise()
        log.info(`[INFO]: Password for ${secretId} successfully changed in Scecrets Manager!`)
        let success = {Timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),Func: 'UpdateSecretInSM', Message: `Secret for ${secretId} successfully changed!`}
        protocol.push(success)
        return
    } catch (err) {
        log.debug("[DEBUG]: Error: ", err.stack);
        let error = {Timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),Func: 'UpdateSecretInSM', Error: err.stack}
        protocol.push(error)
        return
    }
}





/**
 * @function GetSecretFromSM
 * The function retrieves the specified secret from AWS SecretsManager.
 * Returns the password.
 * 
 * @param {string} secretId   - secretId that is available in AWS SecretsManager
 * 
 */
const GetSecretFromSM = async (secretId) => {


    try {
        const data = await SM.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretId}).promise()
        log.debug("[DEBUG]: Secret: ", data);
        let success = {Timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),Func: 'GetSecretFromSM', Message: 'Secret from SecretsManager successfully received!'}
        protocol.push(success)
        const { SecretString } = data
        const password = JSON.parse(SecretString)
        return password.password

    } catch (err) {

        log.debug("[DEBUG]: Error: ", err.stack);
        let error = {Timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),Func: 'GetSecretFromSM', Error: err.stack}
        protocol.push(error)
        return
    }

}


// AWS RDS FUNCTIONS

/**
 * @function ChangeRDSSecret
 * Change the secret of the specified RDS instance.
 * 
 * @param {string} rdsId     - id of the RDS instance
 * @param {string} password  - new password
 * 
 */
const ChangeRDSSecret = async (rdsId,password) => {

    const params = {
        DBInstanceIdentifier: rdsId,
        MasterUserPassword: password
    }



    try {
        await RDS.modifyDBInstance(params).promise() 

        log.info(`[INFO]: Password for ${rdsId} successfully changed!`)
        let success = {Timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), Func: 'ChangeRDSSecret', Message: `Secret for ${rdsId} successfully changed!`}
        protocol.push(success)
        return
    } catch (err) {

        log.debug("[DEBUG]: Error: ", err.stack);
        let error = {Timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), Func: 'ChangeRDSSecret', Error: err.stack}
        protocol.push(error)
        return 

    }

}


const DescribeRDSInstance = async(id) => {


    const params = { DBInstanceIdentifier : id }

    const secondsToWait = 10000

    try {
        let pendingModifications = true

        while (pendingModifications == true) {
            log.info(`[INFO]: Checking modified values for ${id}`)

            let data = await RDS.describeDBInstances(params).promise()
            console.log(data)

            // Extract the 'PendingModifiedValues' object
            let myInstance = data['DBInstances']
            myInstance = myInstance[0]

            if (myInstance.DBInstanceStatus === "resetting-master-credentials") {
                log.info(`[INFO]:Password change is being processed!`)
                 pendingModifications = false

            }

            log.info(`[INFO]: Waiting for ${secondsToWait/1000} seconds!`)
            await waitForSeconds(secondsToWait)
        }


        let success = {Timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), Func: 'DescribeRDSInstance', Message: `${id} available again!`}
        protocol.push(success)
        return 

    } catch (err) {
         log.debug("[DEBUG]: Error: ", err.stack);
        let error = {Timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), Func: 'DescribeRDSInstance', Error: err.stack}
        protocol.push(error)
        return 

    }

}


const WaitRDSForAvailableState = async(id) => {


/**
 * @function WaitRDSForAvailableState
 * Wait for the instance to be available again.
 * 
 * @param {string} id           - id of the RDS instance
 *
 */
    const params = { DBInstanceIdentifier: id}


    try {
        log.info(`[INFO]: Waiting for ${id} to be available again!`)
        const data = await RDS.waitFor('dBInstanceAvailable', params).promise()

        log.info(`[INFO]: ${id} available again!`)
        let success = {Timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), Func: 'WaitRDSForAvailableState', Message: `${id} available again!`}
        protocol.push(success)
        return
    } catch (err) {
        log.debug("[DEBUG]: Error: ", err.stack);
        let error = {Timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), Func: 'WaitRDSForAvailableState', Error: err.stack}
        protocol.push(error)
        return 

    }


}


// AWS ELASTICACHE FUNCTIONS

// ... removed since they follow the same principle like RDS





/////////////////////////////////////////
// Lambda Handler
/////////////////////////////////////////


exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {

    protocol = []
    log.debug("[DEBUG]: Event:", event)
    log.debug("[DEBUG]: Context:", context)

    // Variable for the final message the lambda function will return
    let finalValue



    // Get the password and rds from terraform output
    const secretString = event.secretString // manual input
    const secretId = event.secretId // coming from secretesmanager
    const storageId = event.storageId // coming from db identifier
    const forcedMod = event.forcedMod // manual input


    // Extract the password from the passed secretString to for comparison
    const passedSecretStringJSON = JSON.parse(secretString)
    const passedSecretString = passedSecretStringJSON.password


    const currentSecret = await GetSecretFromSM(secretId)

    // Case if the password has already been updated
    if (currentSecret !== "ChangeMeViaScriptOrConsole" && passedSecretString === "ChangeMeViaScriptOrConsole") {
        log.debug("[DEBUG]: No change necessary.")
        finalValue = {timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), 
            message: 'Lambda function execution finished!', 
            summary: 'Password already updated. It is not "ChangeMeViaScriptOrConsole."'}

        return finalValue
    }   

    // Case if the a new password has not been set yet
    if (currentSecret === "ChangeMeViaScriptOrConsole" && passedSecretString === "ChangeMeViaScriptOrConsole") {
        finalValue = {timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), 
            message: 'Lambda function execution finished!', 
            summary: 'Password still "ChangeMeViaScriptOrConsole". Please change me!'}

        return finalValue
    }

//   Case if the passed password is equal to the stored password and if pw modification is enforced
    if (currentSecret === passedSecretString && forcedMod === "no") {
        finalValue = {timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), 
            message: 'Lambda function execution finished!', 
            summary: 'Stored password is the same as the passed one. No changes made!'}

        return finalValue
    }


    // Case for changing the password
    if (passedSecretString !== "ChangeMeViaScriptOrConsole") {

        // Update the secret in SM for the specified RDS Instances
        await UpdateSecretInSM(secretId,secretString)

        log.debug("[DEBUG]: Secret updated for: ", secretId)

        // Change the new secret vom SM
        const updatedSecret = await GetSecretFromSM(secretId)

        log.debug("[DEBUG]: Updated secret: ", updatedSecret)


        if (secretId.includes("rds")) {

            // Update RDS instance with new secret and wait for it to be available again
            await ChangeRDSSecret(storageId, updatedSecret)
            await DescribeRDSInstance(storageId)
            await WaitRDSForAvailableState(storageId)

        } else if (secretId.includes("elasticache")) {

          // ... removed since it is analogeous to RDS


        } else {

            protocol.push(`No corresponding Storage Id exists for ${secretId}. Please check the Secret Id/Name in the terraform configuration.`)
        }


        finalValue ={timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), 
            message: 'Lambda function execution finished!', 
            summary: protocol}

        return finalValue

    } else {

        finalValue = {timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), 
            message: 'Lambda function execution finished!', 
            summary: 'Nothing changed'}

        return finalValue
    }




}
```

Anyone an idea how to solve or mitigate this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please show the iam policy for your lambda function? By my understanding you might be missing this resource `aws_lambda_permission` for your lambda function. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_permission.html

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",

        "Principal": {
          "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""
      }
    ]
  }

When I start the terraform script, I can see that lambda function is being invoked and also does its actions. But a result never comes back instead the terraform triggers the function again.
The function has waiters implemented i.e. that e.g. it stays within a loop until a database changes it status from 'resetting-credentials' to 'available'.

Comment: When you mean the `result never comes back` do you mean the result by the function or is the function not able to save it in the desired destinantion. e.g. S3. You might also want to check what action's can the lambda perform based on the IAM policy. Can you please show the policy for the lambda function cause the one you showed in this comment is the role I would like to see the policy. Thanks

Comment: What I mean is that the lambda function does its tasks when I look into Cloudwatch. After a while it has finished its tasks then the result should come back into the Terraform output variable. Instead the lambda function is being invoked over and over again. When I delete the while loop in the lambda, everything works.

Comment: I had a similar problem with some backups, it was indeed timeout and re-attempts. To check what was happening I setup a destination onFailure in the Lambda function to send me the error data via e-mail, so I could make sure what was happening. Also, you can just increase the timeout to see if it helps, the default is 3s.